# Substring value Processing in recursion

Tags: xslt

This is all about reverse a string. It works properly for the given Value 'ABCDEF'. The output is also correct 'FEDCBA'. But I want to know how this is printing letters 'A' and 'D' in this string. Could anyone help me to understand this? please.
Elaborate this working method.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template name="reverse">
<xsl:param name="input" select="'ABCDEF'"/>
<xsl:variable name="len" select="string-length($input)"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$len &lt; 2">
<xsl:value-of select="$input"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$len = 2">
<xsl:value-of select="substring($input,2,1)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($input,1,1)"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:variable name="mid" select="floor($len div 2)"/>
<xsl:call-template name="reverse">
<xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring($input,$mid+1,$mid+1)"/>
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:call-template name="reverse">
<xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring($input,1,$mid)"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:call-template name="reverse">
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happens:

Input ABCDEF
len = 6
len is > 2 and not = 2
mid = 3

Call again with input DEF
len = 3
len is > 2 and not = 2
mid = 1

Call again with input EF
len = 2
len is not > 2 but = 2
**Put out the second letter F**
**Put out the first letter E**

Return to outer call
Call with input = D
len is less than 2
**Output D**

Return to outer call
Call again with input = ABC
len = 3
len is > 2 and not 2
mid = 1

Call again with input BC
len = 2
len is not > 2 but = 2
**Put out the second letter C**
**Put out the first letter B**

Return to outer call
Call with input A
len is less than 2
**Output A**

Comment: what is that outer call mean here? I could not understand this

Comment: The template calls itself with half of the input given as long as the input length is greater 2.
Every time one of these 'self-calls' ends because the length is 2 or less though, it returns to the layer above, which is what I was referring to by 'outer call'.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xslrecur/) will help you understand recursion.